# NSMutableArray Values Not Changing

Tags: ios, delegates, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

In my project, I have achievements from the main `GameClass` trying to save data into an `NSMutableArray` in the control class, `ViewController` (which is GameClass's delegate), but the array's values don't seem to change. Here's my code:

In GameClass.m

```
NSLog(@"test %i",[delegate getAchievement:3]);
[delegate setAchievement:3];
NSLog(@"test %i",[delegate getAchievement:3]);
```

In ViewController.m

```
-(void)setAchievement: (int)number{

     [achievements replaceObjectAtIndex: number withObject: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1]];
     NSLog(@"setachievement was called");

     [self saveData];
}

-(int)getAchievement: (int)number{

    return [[achievements objectAtIndex: number] intValue];
}
```

And what I get is:

```
 2012-11-25 20:47:14.754 Stickman Parkour 2[25109:c07] test 0
 2012-11-25 20:47:14.755 Stickman Parkour 2[25109:c07] setachievement was called
 2012-11-25 20:47:14.755 Stickman Parkour 2[25109:c07] test 0
```

Comment: `delegate` is probably `nil`

Comment: @borrrden That was my first thought but if delegate is `nil` how come it is logging "set achievement was called"?

Comment: Either delegate is nil or achievements is nil.  A call to `nil` returns zero/nil.  (But since "set achievement was called" appears, that suggests that delegate is OK and achievements is what's nil.)

Comment: @HotLicks Yup, that was it. I was setting "achievements" to [userDefaults objectForKey: @"achievements"], which is nil the first time you run it. Post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either delegate is nil or achievements is nil. A call to nil returns zero/nil. (But since "set achievement was called" appears, that suggests that delegate is OK and achievements is what's nil.)